Degree of a smooth map to a product

Let $f:M\rightarrow S^{n-1}\times [0,1]$ be a smooth map, where $M$ is a $n$-manifold with boundary. Suppose $f(\partial M)\subset S^{n-1}\times \{0,1\}$. Denote $\partial_-M:=f^{-1}(S^{n-1}\times\{0\})$, $\partial_+M:=f^{-1}(S^{n-1}\times\{1\})$. Write $f=(g,t)$ as components, i.e. $g=p_1\circ f$ and $t=p_2\circ f$.


Claim. $deg(f)=\pm deg(g|_{\partial_-M})$.


Proof. We can find $t_0$ such that $t_0^{-1}(\{0\})=\partial_-M$ and $t_0^{-1}(\{1\})=\partial_+M$ and $dt_0\neq 0$ on $\partial M$. We can make $t_0$ homotopic to $t$ and hence $f$ homotopic to $f_0=(g,t_0)$. CLEARLY, $deg(f_0)=\pm deg(g|_{\partial_-M})$. Then the claim follows.

I have two questions. 1) How to find $t_0$? 2) The CLEARLY part is totally unclear to me. Why is this true?
I have worked out the following.
Step 1. Let $\omega^S$ denote the volume form on $S^{n-1}$ and $\omega^I$ the volume form on $[0,1]$. Then the volume form of $S^{n-1}\times [0,1]$ is $\omega:=p_1^*\omega^S\cup p_2^*\omega^I$. Then $\int_{S^{n-1}\times [0,1]}p_1^*\omega^S\cup p_2^*\omega^I=\int_{S^{n-1}}\omega^S$?
Step 2. $f_0^*(p_1^*\omega^S\cup p_2^*\omega^I)=g^*\omega^S\cup t_0^*\omega^I$. And $\int_M g^*\omega^S\cup t_0^*\omega^I=deg(f_0)\int_{S^{n-1}\times [0,1]}\omega=deg(f_0)\int_{S^{n-1}}\omega^S$. The last equality is step 1.
Step 3. $\int_{\partial_-M}(g|_{\partial_-M})^*\omega^S=deg(g|_{\partial_-M})\int_{S^{n-1}}\omega^S$.
So it is sufficient to show $\int_{\partial_-M}(g|_{\partial_-M})^*\omega^S=\int_M g^*\omega^S\cup t_0^*\omega^I$.
UPDATE. I think local degree formula is of some use.

I believe I have a solution. Let me post it later
